# How do I clear/delete a grocery item in React?

Tags: reactjs

How do I clear/delete a grocery item? I need to make a button that clears a grocery item after I click it. TIA

Here's the code this is for a HW assignment:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    grocery: grocery,
    item: '',
    brand: '',
    units: Number,
    quantity: Number,
    isPurchased: Boolean
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const addGrocery = {
      item: this.state.item,
      brand: this.state.brand,
      units: this.state.units,
      quantity: this.state.quantity,

    }

  this.setState({
    grocery: [addGrocery, ...this.state.grocery],
    item: '',
    brand: '',
    units: Number,
    quantity: Number,
  })

  const removeGrocery = {
    item: this.state.item
  }

}
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this question earlier with a different account?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some codes bro. I fixed something that will give you error in future.

```
const initialValue = {
grocery: grocery,
item: '',
brand: '',
units: 1,
quantity: 2,
isPurchased: false
}

class App extends Component {
state = initialValue;

handleChange = (e) => {
    // added a spread iterator
    this.setState({...this.state, [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
}

reset = ()=> {this.setState(initialValue)}  // set to initialValue is clearing current state to initial state
```